# Rust socket-io wait for disconnect?

Tags: rust, socket.io

I'm running into an issue trying to use `rust_socketio` where the emit method either hangs the execution (with the loop), or because it's async runs past the emit call and I never get the callback (without the loop). Does rust_socketio have a standard way to wait for some kind of signal here? I don't see anything demonstrating it in the docs and I can't find many uses of the client on github.

I want the blocking behavior of calling emit in the loop, but I don't see how to let the execution continue once it gets called. I tried calling `socket.disconnect()` from within the callback but it still hangs.

EDIT: it does not actually block using the loop, I'm working on figuring out how to make it block

```
fn main() {
    loop {
        // ... get some user input
        let socket = ClientBuilder::new("http://localhost:3000")
            .on("custom_event", response_handler)
            .on("error", |err, _| eprintln!("Error: {:#?}", err))
            .connect()
            .expect("Connection failed");
        let _result = socket.emit("custom_event", json!({ "query": input })).unwrap();
        // The callbacks are triggered happily, and the socket is disconnected, but...
        // execution hangs here and the print is never run
        println!("hello...?");
    }
}
```

https://docs.rs/rust_socketio/latest/rust_socketio/client/struct.Client.html#method.emit

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It wasn't actually hanging, the output from the callback was masking the fact that it had finished the loop and returned to the input stage. I just need to figure out how to wait on the connection now.

I used a static AtomicBool to hold the main function up until the callback had completed one way or the other.

```
static IS_HANDLING_RESPONSES: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);
```

then in the main loop:

```
        let _result = socket
            .emit("custom_event", json!({ "query": input }))
            .expect("Failed to emit");
        while IS_HANDLING_RESPONSES.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            // wait for the server to respond
        }
```

and then in the callback when we reach a completion state:

```
IS_HANDLING_RESPONSES.swap(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
```

Another option I found that avoids a global is to use channels to communicate back to the main function. I made a function that returns a closure that has access to the transmitter for a channel.

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;

fn response_handler(is_done: Sender<bool>, payload: Payload, _socket: RawClient) {
// ... implementation
    // when it's time to wrap up use the channel
    _ = is_done.send(true);
// ...
}

fn make_response_handler(is_done: Sender<bool>) -> impl Fn(Payload, RawClient) {
    move |payload: Payload, socket: RawClient| {
        response_handler(is_done.clone(), payload, socket);
    }
}
```

And then in the main loop:

```
    let (is_done, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let handler = make_response_handler(is_done);
    // ... go get input
    let _result = socket
        .emit("custom_event", json!({ "query": input }))
        .expect("Failed to emit");
    // This blocks until the callback sends back a completion message
    let _is_done = rx.recv();
```